# plist as persistent storage for storing and retrieving data between closing and restarting app

Tags: iphone, plist

I am trying to save few property into the plist when the user starts the app for the first time, and then I have to retrieve those data and show it to the user, when the user restart the app, so that I don't have to ask for the same data again.

I am guessing this should be very straight forward, but may be I am missing something.

It would be nice if some one can point me to a sample code for doing the same thing, it would be nice if the code saves and retrieves the data from dictionary to plist and from plist to dictionary.

I looked into the Apple Property List Programming guide and used the code from Reading and Writing Property list data

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1

but, when i restart my app, I don't get back the data that I have stored.

****EDIT****

I am adding some code so that some one can point out if I am making any mistake.

I created a plist file "Data.plist" in my project Resources folder.

This is how I save data in one of my view controller

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
//NSString *error;

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


[dict setObject:@"xxxxxx" forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
[dict setObject:@"password" forKey:@"password"];
[dict setObject:@"email" forKey:@"email"];

[dict writeToFile:finalPath atomically:NO];
```

This is how I am reading the the data on the same view controller viewDidLoad method, because I want to load the data from when next time app starts.

```
    NSDictionary *dictionary;

// read "Data.plist" from application bundle
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];

// dump the contents of the dictionary to the console
for (id key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"bundle: key=%@, value=%@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Before saving to the file i can do "po dict" at gdb and can see there are data in the file

NSLog print following error

Assertion failed: (cls), function getName, file /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.

Because when i load data and do "po dictionary" at gdb it is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-[NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically:]` returns `YES` or `NO` depending on whether it's successful or not. Are you checking the return value?

If I had to take a guess, I'd say it's because you're writing the file into the application bundle. You should write it elsewhere in the file system; `~/Library/Application Support/<application name>` is the usual location.

**Edit:**

You can check the return value with something like:

```
BOOL success = [dict writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Could not write file");
}
```

Comment: [dict writeToFile:finalPath atomically:NO]; I have to specify NO  or YES when I am writing this statement isn't it, how do I check what is the return value.     But if I write it to file system is it going to be iphone file system, what path should I give is the path ~/Library/Application Support/<application name> is available in iphone too as finally the app has to go to the iphone.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to check the return value. (Also, if this is for the iPhone, you should tag it with `iphone` or `cocoa-touch`, not `cocoa`.)

Comment: Thanks, I checked  the value of success is true, so which means the log is not getting printed, which means that the data is written in the file

Comment: Actually some other user made the tag has cocoa, i didn't do it